# How can I detect a KeyPress event in UITextField?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, keypress

In `UITextView` there is a **Changed** event to handle keypress. However the `UITextField` has not such event.

How can I detect a KeyPress event in `UITextField`?

There is a method described [here](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=864) using notifications, however the problem I have is that I cannot unsubscribe from the TextFieldTextDidChangeNotification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which is your question. The first one you seem to have answered yourself, i.e.
the solution (from your link) is to use `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver`.

The second is about *unsubscribing* - if you want to stop observing you should call the previous method counterpart, i.e. `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver`.

Just keep the object returned from `AddObserver` so you can supply it to `RemoveObserver`.

**note:** If I did not understand your question correctly please use **edit** and add some details and/or code of what you want to achieve and we'll do our best to help :-)

Comment: thanks poupou, I was hopping that there might be an easier method. Holding a reference at the object returned from AddObserver I was able to unsubscribe from the notification

Answer (score 2):

As colinta suggested, do this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  NSLog(@"range = %@, replacement = %@, text = %@", NSStringFromRange(range), string, text);
  return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"clear text");
  return YES;
}
```

It will also work if the input was changed via spelling suggestions.

Comment: This won't work if you need to respond to keypresses outside of the scope of text field editing.  For example, say you need to capture a single keypress and move to the next field.  You cannot do that using this method. You have to use the keyboard events.

Comment: This is a good answer that will solve the problem for many use cases (for example mine) where it is the data change itself that is concern. And if it is the change in edit mode is the concern, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` are the delegate methods to use. @GregPasquariello is technically correct... the delegate won't catch people clicking around in the text field in general, but in most cases, there probably isn't a need to detect that kind of activity in a text field.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the UITextFieldDelegate

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Implement that protocol.  It has call back methods for all the text field changes.

Comment: I was able to use the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method, which *is* fired on every keypress, as near as I can tell.  The bummer, though, is that you have to study the `replacementString:` value, because the `textField.text` property will not be updated yet when this message is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to observe `UITextField` changes is

```
_textField.AddTarget((sender, e) =>
{
    // Do your stuff in here
}, UIControlEvent.EditingChanged);
```

You don't have to subscribe to a system-wide notification center and you don't have to unregister observer when you're destroing a text field.

Hope this will help someone in the future :)