# How to change Keyboard's return type,iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have 2 textfields.I am checking when the both textfields are filled, than, i change the keyboard return button to "Go".Else, it will remain as "Return".
Its working fine, the keyboard's return type changes,only, when i tap on textfield.
I want, to change it automatically, once both the textfields are non-empty.

I tried putting my code

```
if ([txtEmail.text length] > 0 && [txtPass.text length] > 0) {
    // Set the return key here, e.g:
    txtEmail.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
    txtPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
}
else {
    // Set the return key here, e.g: 
    txtEmail.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    txtPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
}
```

at

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{}
```

but its not working for me.

Any idea, how can i change the return button from return to Go, when both he fields are non empty,automatically, user don't have tap on any text field to change it.

Comment: might be you can try using method -  (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField              shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range              replacementString:(NSString *)string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set delegate for both textfields.then put your code in viewDidLoad once after creating reference of UItextFields

```
if ([txtEmail.text length] > 0 && [txtPass.text length] > 0) 
{
txtEmail.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
txtPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
}
else 
{

txtEmail.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
txtPass.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`textFieldDidBeginEditting` fires **before editing started**, so obviously the text does not change there.

What you need to do is to detect **key press** to discover changes and based on that change returnKey type. See this question: [How can I detect a KeyPress event in UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044288/how-can-i-detect-a-keypress-event-in-uitextfield) - it deals with *key press* events.

Answer (score 1):

```
//have you set the delegate of your textField if not then please set it.. 

txtEmail.delegate = self;
txtPass.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

check in your header file `UITextFieldDelegate` protocal and

do not forget to set delegate to self.

```
txtEmail.delegate = self;
txtPass.delegate = self;
```